# Playing all files in a directory with MPlayer for Windows

Tags: windows, command-line, mplayer

Using:

```
mplayer "path\to\media\*.*"
```

doesn't work with MPlayer for Windows.

How do I play all files in a directory?

Comment: Try the manual page: http://www.mplayerhq.hu/DOCS/man/en/

Comment: @MichaelFrank: I didn't find it in the 147-page manual. That's why I turned here. So, if you know the lines/section, please tell.

Comment: @antonio: Does something like `for /r "C:\Music" %a in (*.mp3) do @mplayer "%~a"` help?

Comment: The code snippet in your question answered mine on how to glob all files in a directory for mplayer on linux. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is now clear there is no option to play a folder in MPlayer. So we have to turn to the OS services.
The choice much depends on your creativity, anyway, for the Command Prompt  `forfiles` is rather standard (and a bit shorter than `for`):

```
forfiles /p "path\to\media" /c "mplayer \"@file"
```

Add `/s` before `/p` to recourse subdirs.

Of course, use MPlayer path if its directory is not in the `PATH` variable.

In Powershell replace `\"` with `0x22`:

```
forfiles /p "path\to\media" /c "0x22mplayer0x22 0x22@file"
```

If you prefer something more native:

```
dir -file -r "path\to\media" | % {mplayer $_.fullname}
```

To recourse subdirs, use `-r` near `-file`.

None of these command is a breeze to type, therefore you might want to wrap them in a batch script.

Answer (score 1):

A nice way is to make playlists and play by i.e.

```
  mplayer -loop 0 -playlist album.m3u
```

If you are in a directory of mp3 files you can pipe them to mplayer. On Windows it would be

```
 mplayer dir *.mp3.
```

This will result in mplayer playing all mp3 files in directory. Keyboard controls like next / > are working now as well.

Easiest way to create playlists are by commandline, ie: on MSwindows

```
DIR *.mp3 /A-D/B/S/ON > playlist.m3u
```

will add all files in current and all subfolders to playlist.m3u.

Comment: `mplayer dir *.mp3` doesn't work for me. It tries to play the file `dir`. Also `dir *.mp3 | mplayer`  doesn't work.   I have seen that I can play files like this: `mplayer song1.mp3 song2.mp3 ...`; but how to pipe the songs? I have MPlayer Redxii-SVN-r36243-4.6.3

Comment: commands can be joined, i have script like that in .cmd that is in path on windows: `dir *.mts,*mp4 /A-D/B/S/ON > "%TEMP%\mp_playlist.txt" && mplayer.exe -loop 0 -playlist "%TEMP%\mp_playlist.txt"`

Answer (score 0):

I am able to use commands to run all MP3 files under a folder as below.

1st line: Add MP3 files to a playlist file (`playlist.m3u`).
2nd line: Play the playlist file in Windows Media Player.

```
dir path\to\media /A-D/B/S/ON > playlist.m3u
start "wmplayer" path\to\playlist.m3u
```